# MySQL performance issue due to multiple date fields

Tags: mysql, performance

I have this problem; I have two tables, one that I'll call tableA, and a second one, tableB.

Between two tables there is a relation 1:n and in both of them there are date fields; let me explain with an example

```
TableA
id|dateA|others

TableB
id|id_tablea|dateb1|sold|dateb2
```

The join between these tables is trivial, my problem is when I have to filter by date; as requirement, I have to use d

1) dateb2 if and only if sold = 1 ( if record on tableb is present )
2) else dateb1 ( if record on tableb is present )
3) datea1

This is an example of query:

```
SELECT * FROM
tableA ta
LEFT JOIN
tableB tb on ta.id = tb.id_tablea
WHERE 
(
if(tb.sold=1,tb.dateb2,( IFNULL(tb.dateb1,ta.datea1))
)
BETWEEN 'INT1'  AND 'INT2'
AND >
...
```

My problem is that both tables are very big and the query takes a very long time; how can I optimize this query? any Idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check similar questions that are listed on the column in the right. You will see the approach people take, from providing sufficient information to what optimizations are. We can't do anything with your query, without any idea how much information you're returning, what "very big" means in your terms (we have numbers in IT, we can use them to express magnitude) and what MySQL does behind the scenes + what the configuration of your server is.

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to get rid of the if/else:

I assume that if sold is not yet 1, dateb2 is invalid or could carry any arbitrary value. You could then keep dateb2 equal to dateb1 as long as sold != 1. Then you could always select on dateb2, no matter if sold is set or not.

And you could now create an index for dateb2, which would probably increase performance, too.

If the assumption above is wrong, you could consider having an additional column dateb3, which is kept equal to dateb2, if sold == 1, and equal to dateb1 otherwise, together with an index over dateb3.